# Zend Navigation - various navigation blocks

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation, zend-acl

I have a `navigation.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <nav>
        <programm_nav>
            <label></label>
            <uri>#</uri>
            <pages>
                <all>
                    <label>test1</label>
                    <resource>default:programme</resource>
                    <module>default</module>
                    <controller>programme</controller>
                    <action>list</action>
                    <privilege>index</privilege>
                </all>                      
            </pages>
        </programm_nav>
        <acc_nav>
        <label></label>
            <uri>#</uri>
            <pages>
                <ueb>
                    <label>test2</label>
                    <resource>default:account</resource>
                    <module>default</module>
                    <controller>account</controller>
                    <action>index</action>
                    <privilege>index</privilege>
                </ueb>                      
            </pages>
        </acc_nav>
    </nav>
</config>
```

This config file defines two navigation boxes, one programm_nav and the other acc_nav.

In my bootstrap I do the following:

```
$navContainerConfig = new Zend_Config_Xml ( APPLICATION_PATH .
'/configs/navigation.xml', 'nav');     

$navContainer = new Zend_Navigation ( $navContainerConfig );

$view->navigation ( $navContainer )->setAcl ( $this->_acl )
->setRole ( Zend_Registry::get ( 'role' ) );
```

In my view I display the navigation:

```
$navSec = $this->navigation ()->findOneByLabel ( 'acc_nav' );
echo $this->navigation ()->menu ()->renderMenu ( $navSec );
```

But no matter how I define `$navSec` I always displays `programm_nav` and never another box. `acc_nav` is never displayed.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findOneByLabel('acc_nav');` will search for text in `<label>`-tags as there is nog **acc_nav** value. It won't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated this and this is what happened ....

I get two links, one for `test1` and one for `test2`.

I have to remove the code for your `ACL` because I do not have it, so try removing this. If it then works you then know that the setup of your `ACL` is incorrect.

I just set the nav contained to the registry then got it back in the script file. This may well not be the best way, but given the ZF docs on this, it was my only solution. It may well be documented better now.

In my Bootstrap I have

```
function _initNav()
{
    $navContainerConfig = new Zend_Config_Xml ( APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'nav');     

    $navContainer = new Zend_Navigation ( $navContainerConfig );

    Zend_Registry::set("navigation", $navContainer);        
}
```

And my view file looks like this

```
<?php

    $navSec = $this->navigation(Zend_Registry::get("navigation"))
        ->findOneByLabel( 'acc_nav' );

    echo $this->navigation()->menu()->renderMenu( $navSec );

?>
```